# Dynamic class creation with Fields from other classes

Tags: java, reflection, aop

Example:

```
public class MyObject{
    @SerializedName("hello")
    @NotNull @MaxLength(256) @NotEmpty
    private String hello;
}

public class MyOtherObject{
    @SerializedName("world")
    @NotNull @MaxLength(512) @NotEmpty
    private String world;
}
```

How to dynamically generate a class MyDynamicHelloWorldObject such that it becomes the equivalent of:

```
public class MyDynamicHelloWorldObject{
    @SerializedName("hello")
    @NotNull @MaxLength(256) @NotEmpty
    private String hello;

    @SerializedName("world")
    @NotNull @MaxLength(512) @NotEmpty
    private String world;
}
```

Looking for solutions because copying and pasting is going to lead to errors, especially when code is changed in the future.

Comment: This question suffers from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). You are not describing the problem you want to solve but the solution you think should be applied, but without any detail or background information. The solution is most likely wrong or at least horribly bad design. Possibly aggregation is a better way to solve this, but with that little information I can just speculate. My feeling when reading this is: "Wow, that's just such a bad idea!"

Comment: You think that it's XY because you do not understand what it can be used for. Ask yourself how many times you have declared a variable for the same thing in model/dao/dto/whatever. Which is bad design? Making it automatic or having to rewrite everything again and again and again? Now think what happens when there're tons of annotations. Now think what happens when code's updated. Your feeling is wrong, and you have no idea what's going on.

Comment: No, because you didn't explain anything it is XY, and as a consequence I (or anyone else) cannot understand what you want to achieve. You just proved that it is XY! Because you don't explain, everyone has "no idea what's going on", as you say correctly. So thanks for starting to explain. But that's not enough and I still think your idea is bad after you explained a bit: _(to be continued)_

Comment: If you generate a class dynamically, where does the code using that class come from? It also has to be generated or it has to use reflection. Even if you have source code for it, against what should it compile if the classes it uses do not exist yet? I understand that you want to avoid boilerplate code, but this is the wrong way. One idea might be to use APT (annotation processing) in order to do the code generation. Anyway, it is still speculation without a complete [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing how you want to use the resulting code.

Comment: MCVE is already there. i want to create a new class with whatever fields that I want together with the annotations that are declared in the original class, so that I don't have to maintain multiple copies of the same variable across many classes. I do not care how it is done, only that it is dynamic, and can achieve the goal of making the equivalent of the end result. What I can discern from your reply is, do it myself. Fine.

Comment: I would not have spent time to write three (now four) comments if I would not want to help. But I think I am done here now. Sorry for obviously being unable to explain to you in a way you can understand why I asked for more information and also being unable to motivate you to answer my questions. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it recommended way. You can create file MyDynamicHelloWorldObject.java by combining two file as below,

```
String fileName1 = "MyObject.java";
String fileName2 = "MyOtherObject.java";

//read and write with try-with-resources
try (Stream<String> stream1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName1));
    Stream<String> stream2 = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName2));
    BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("MyDynamicHelloWorldObject.java"))) {

    //first line 
    writer1.write("public class MyDynamicHelloWorldObject{\n");
    //merge two streams and skip first line as it has class name
    Stream.concat(stream1.skip(1),stream2.skip(1)).forEach(line->{try {
        writer1.write(line+"\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //error handling
    }});
} catch (IOException e) {
    //error handling
}
}
```